# GetItemByID very slow on big list for non-privileged users and quick for site admins in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have large list (about 20 000 items) and standard Sharepoint 2010 display form which internally invokes method SPList.GetItemById(id). This method executes sql query to get item by its id from content database.

The problem is the method SPList.GetItemById(id) is executed 10-20 times longer for non-privileged user then for site admin. And as result it takes 10 sec to open display form for non-privileged user and less then 1 sec for site admin.

I figured out with help of profiler that bottle neck is in SQL-query which Sharepoint 2010 constructs for non-privileged user.

SQL queries are different for non-privileged user and for site admin.

Could you please suggest solution or workaround to increase performance for non-privileged users?

I use standard Sharepoint 2010 display form so I cannot replace SPList.GetItemById(id) method with other more quick method.

May be it will be of some help: SQL query for non-privileged user has some additional joins compered to site admin:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT CAST(val AS uniqueidentifier) AS InValues
FROM dbo.fn_UnpackCsvString(@L3TXP) ) AS Scopes ON (t1.ScopeId = Scopes.InValues)

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM AllUserData AS t32_u 
WITH(NOLOCK,INDEX=AllUserData_PK) INNER JOIN Docs AS t32_d 
WITH(NOLOCK) ON (t32_d.DoclibRowId =t32_u.tp_ID  AND
t32_u.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0  AND
t32_u.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x  AND
t32_u.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND
(t32_d.SiteId=t32_u.tp_SiteId) AND
(t32_d.SiteId = @SITEID) AND
(t32_d.ParentId = t32_u.tp_ParentId) AND
(t32_d.Id = t32_u.tp_DocId) AND
( (t32_u.tp_Level = 1) ) AND
(t32_d.Level = t32_u.tp_Level) AND
(t32_d.IsCurrentVersion = 1) AND
(t32_d.Level = 1 OR t32_d.Level =  2) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT CAST(val AS uniqueidentifier) AS InValues 
FROM dbo.fn_UnpackCsvString(@L3TXP) ) AS Scopes ON
(t32_d.ScopeId = Scopes.InValues)) AS t32 ON
(t32.[tp_ListId] = @L2) AND
```

where table Docs AS t1

Answer (score 0):

Needs to mention than every item in the list has its own set of permissions.

So it looks like [SharePoint performance degradation with a large number of unique security scopes in lists](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2420771/en-us)